# "Not just be about X" versus "not be just about X"

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

I've had two different native English speakers suggest one or the other as the correct grammatical usage of this expression. The full sentence I'm trying to write is of the form, "X should not be just about Y". What is the correct usage here, and why? A Google search failed and I lack English grammar books or even the knowledge of what kind of grammatical construct this is and hence where to look for an answer.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What Google search? Try "not just be" and "not be just".

Comment: I tried that, to no avail. (Actually, this page shows up as the first result now!)

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth answered:

> 'Just' here is a *limiting modifier*. These (others are only, hardly ...) can be placed (carefully!) in various positions in the sentence, often right before the words they are restricting. Only Hermione looked at the basilisk. Hermione only looked at the basilisk (she didn't attack it). Hermione looked at only the basilisk (not at Tom Riddle). / However, placement is sometimes less well defined. With modals, "X should not be about just Y" might be expected, but "X should not be just about Y" is idiomatic and formal, and "X should not just be about Y" is perhaps more idiomatic but less formal.

Comment: This answers my question perfectly, thank you. As perhaps to be expected, there isn't a clear-cut answer as far as English usage is concerned! Given the context the writing is for, however, I will stick to the formal usage as you've indicated. Thank you! (I've upvoted your answer but lack enough reputation for it to publicly change the vote count, sadly!)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s enough context to be talking about formality. I suggest that with the wording given, it’s more important to talk about actual meaning which, yes, is far too often confused by idiomatic rather than correct usage.

“Not just be about X” strictly means that more than simply having X as a subject, the article, or whatever, should also, for instance, be well written or grammatically correct, or merely contain a certain number of words.

For example, “the article should not just be about Trump; it should also be humorous and authoritative enough to persuade people to vote for Trump… (or against him, depending on the slant the editor wants)…” That’s more about the process; the way something is written.

“Not be just about X” strictly ignores the above, while specifying that the piece should have other subjects beside X.

For example, “the article should not be just about Trump; it should also talk about Washington, Lincoln and other Presidents…” That’s more about the content; not the way the thing is written, but what it’s written about.

None of that changes the fact that in real speech, huge numbers of native speakers put such limiting modifiers anywhere they first think of, rather than where they thinking about where they ought to be.

(Has Edwin’s comment been deleted, or why can’t I see it, please anyone?)